# How to set up cypress run for TypeScript in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, cypress, pnpm

I have a project build in TypeScript and I would like to use cypress run to run my unit test. Everything works when I trigger command line from terminal, but how can I set up cypress run with WebStorm IDE under `Run/Debug Configuration`? The only possibility is to set up npm command but my project is using `pnpm` not `npm`.

So how can I set up cypress run under `Run/Debug configuration`?

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm doesn't provide any special support for Cypress (feel free to upvote and comment [WEB-32819](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32819) to increase its priority and to be notified on updates). But you can still use [Node.js](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html) run configurations to start your scripts.

[image]

I'd also suggest trying a third-party [Cypress-Pro](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13987-cypress-support-pro) plugin